# Devise - Trying to redirect to login page on session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I'm attempting to follow the suggestions on other stack overflow posts, but without any luck.

Right now when the user session times out and the user tries to interact with the page, I get two 401 Unauthorized errors in the console. I would like it to redirect to the login page instead.

I found with some digging that I can create my own custom failure app and override redirect_url to have it always redirect. This is what I have:

in /config/initializers/devise.rb

require "custom_timeout_redirect"

```
config.warden do |manager|
manager.failure_app = CustomTimeoutRedirect
end
```

in custom_timeout_redirect.rb:

```
class CustomTimeoutRedirect < Devise::FailureApp
   def redirect_url
      puts 'TRYING TO REDIRECT TO THE HOMEPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGE'
      puts scope_url
      scope_url
   end
```

This code is not run when the session times out. What's more, I've attempted to override the redirect method as well, and it seems that it isn't being invoked on session timeout either.

Could someone steer me in the right direction here? I've read this solution to this problem on the web enough to where I'm thinking I'm just being dumb.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order for user to redirect to signin. I believe you should use the `Timeoutable` instead http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Timeoutable

And comment out this line in config/initializers/devise.rb `config.timeout_in = 30.minutes`

If you want to define a custom timeout duration you could do something like this:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if self.admin? 
      1.year
    else
      2.days
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!